# Find Largest Number in a File

Tags: java, file, numbers

Is java able to read a file and give out the max value that it contains?

Comment: Yes, java can read files, and you can do programmy things with the data to find the max value.

Comment: That should be possible, but solution depends on what you mean by "value".

Comment: @Pshemo a String followed by a number-value. But the program should only read the number. String is irrelevant.

Comment: Then iterate over such [string][number] tokens, separate [number] part from it, compare to current maximal value and if new number is bigger store it as current max. Repeat until there are no more [string][number] tokens in file. If you have problem with either of those steps please ask about them *specifically*,

Comment: Where are you at with your java skills? Can you write, compile and run a program? Then you should start breaking your task into chunks, "How do I read a file?" "How do I parse a number from a String?" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two cases . 
Case 1 > You want to read file line by line because of file size or you are running on system with less memory . 
[How can I read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Case 2>  Read file chunk by chunk  [Reading file chunk by chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110153/reading-file-chunk-by-chunk)

Once you get the data in memory , you can use max no logic . 
e.g

```
Step 1 > max_no = first no 
step 2> If max_no < input no 
step 3> max_no = input_no
step 4 > continue to read next no till end
```

At the end , you will get maximum of input nos in max_no

I hope it helps

Comment: This is not a bad check-list to write it. Thanks. Accepted as answer